# Contract arbitrary call function fails to execute an ERC20 transfer

Tags: solidity

I have a contract with the following function that executes calls with the supplied parameters (recipient, value, and data).

```
function execute(
    /*
        @dev: Function to execute a transaction with arbitrary parameters. Handles 
        all withdrawals, etc. Can be used for token transfers, eth transfers, 
        or anything else.
    */
    address r,
    uint256 v,
    bytes memory d
    ) private {
   /*
     @dev: Gas efficient arbitrary call in assembly.
   */
    assembly {
        let success_ := call(gas(), r, v, add(d, 0x00), mload(d), 0x20, 0x0)
        let success := eq(success_, 0x1)
        if iszero(success) {
            revert(mload(d), add(d, 0x20))
        }
    }
}
```

The solidity equivalent of the function is following solidity code:

```
function execute(address recipient, uint _value, bytes memory _data) private {
    (bool success,) = recipient.call{value: _value}(_data);
    require(success, "Call failed.");
}
```

It works fine for Ethereum transfers, but I try to use it to withdraw an ERC20 token from the contract, it reverts, and I don't know why. I tried using tenderly to see what is going on, but in this particular case it was not properly identifying where the revert is occurring, maybe because of it can't read assembly?

I wrote a function to encode a transfer call for an ERC20 token:

```
function getTransfer(address dest, uint256 amount) external pure returns(bytes memory){
    return abi.encodeWithSignature(
            "transfer(address,uint256)",
            dest,
            amount
        );
}
```

Which generated the following data that I sent to the contract (removed actual address) :

0xa9059cbb00000000000000000000000xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000de0b6b3a7640000

I called the token's address with a value of 0 and the above data, and it reverted. I sort of assumed that this would work and I had already sent some tokens to the contract, also because I wanted to challenge myself (luckily did not send more). Are they stuck, or can someone tell me what is going on? What am I missing?

**Update**: I deployed a new contract to test, and I tested both the solidity and YUL execute functions. The solidity version works, while the assembly version does not. So it is something with the assembly call() syntax is my guess at this point.

Comment: can you try to add uint256 from the solidity function OR check bytes memory _data  ??? && do you have always the money on your contract after the error appear ? Post your error .. log .

Comment: The entire transaction reverts, and there isn't a specific message, just says "execution reverted". And yes because it reverts, the funds are still in the contract. I am not sure what you mean "try to add uint256 or check bytes memory _data"? I will try to gather some more info and post it here.

Comment: I added some more info, updated original question.

Comment: Try add : contract YOURCONTRACTNAME is Ownable { ...  receive() external payable {} } ||| and functions add : external onlyOwner {..}

Comment: The contract already has custom authentication functionality and it does have receive() enabled

Answer (score 0):

Example of a simple transfer from SmartContract to WalletAdd in Solidity if that can help you ?:

```
function transfer(address tokenAddress) external onlyOwner  {
    IERC20 token = IERC20(tokenAddress);
    token.transfer(msg.sender, token.balanceOf(address(this)));
}

receive() external payable {}
```